# Mac OSX server command equivalent for dhclient?

Tags: networking, mac-osx, dhcp, dhclient

Is there an MacOS command that makes a dhcp request, and renews the old lease, drops it for a new one, or usefully reports errors or lack of response from a dhcp server?

This would both help fix networking on the machine after problems on the network without rebooting and would also be useful to diagnose wider networking problems from a mac.

I can not find any command equivalent of `dhclient` though obviously some component must be serving this purpose. The question is, is that component exposed to a command line interface?

I am biased to the command line for these features and may have overlooked settings panels or tools that might solve it using a gui interface.

I believe this question is at the heart of this other question: [Is there an equivalent command for 'init.d/networking restart' in OS X](https://serverfault.com/questions/140327/is-there-an-equivalent-command-for-init-d-networking-restart-in-os-x)

Comment: Good question but is there any particular reason you're not doing this through the GUI?

Comment: GUI's are subjected to more changes and the results are harder to capture where as the commands could even be an

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To renew the lease:

`sudo ipconfig set <interface> DHCP`

Usually interface is **en0** or **en1**.

To see all the gory details, run `sudo ipconfig setverbose 1` before you run the above, then tail */var/log/system.log*.  After you're done, remember to run `sudo ipconfig setverbose 0` to turn it off again.

Comment: Usually happens to me when I lock my Mac and log in to my session back again I lost DNS config or resolv.conf doesn't work. So this command saved me the task of disconnecting and reconnecting back to the network to fix it. Thanks.

Comment: I did `sudo ipconfig setverbose 1`and then `sudo ipconfig set <my special lan interface> DHCP` but no output on console nor new output in system.log.